# Passing pig macro parameters

Tags: apache-pig

I have a pig macro

```
define chop_massive (my, maxev) returns grouped, massive {
  gr = foreach (group $my by id) generate group as id, $my;
  split gr into
    massive if COUNT($my) > $maxev,
    grouped otherwise;
  $grouped = grouped;
  $massive = foreach massive generate id, COUNT($my) as $my;
};
```

my problem is with passing `maxev` parameter.
when I use a constant literal (e.g., `100L`) all is fine.
however, I want to use `$MAX_EVENTS` specified using `-param` on the command line.

I tried

```
A, massive = chop_massive(A, $MAX_EVENTS);
```

and got

```
mismatched input '100L' expecting set null
```

I tried

```
A, massive = chop_massive(A, ($MAX_EVENTS));
```

and got

```
mismatched input '(' expecting set null
```

I tried

```
A, massive = chop_massive(A, '$MAX_EVENTS');
```

and got

```
Macro doesn't support user defined schema that contains name that conflicts with alias name: A
```

I tried

```
massive if COUNT($my) > $MAX_EVENTS,
```

inside the macro and got

```
Macro inline failed for macro 'chop_massive'. Reason: Undefined parameter : MAX_EVENTS
```

(this error is at least clear and reasonable).

So what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't see it documented anywhere, it wouldn't surprise me if expressions are not supported as macro arguments. Why not just pass `$EVENTS_PER_DAY` and `$DAYS` as parameters to the macro (three parameters instead of two)?

Comment: I believe the error you just got is not related to the parameter substitution -- it's because you have used `A` as an alias name in both your macro return and elsewhere in the script. Try changing that to something else.